# PHP / IIS High CPU + Recursive Process

Tags: php, windows-server-2012, iis-8, process-explorer

I just uploaded and ran a PHP file that would output the user that PHP is running as, however, the process started to eat up all of the CPU.

I had a look in Process Explorer and it appeared that PHP was creating a command line process, which created a PHP process, which created another command line process etc etc.

Any idea why this would happen? This is the PHP code that caused it:

```
<?php
    echo `whoami`;
?>
```

Windows Server 2012, running PHP 5.5.6 through IIS.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you adjust your script and try <?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>

Comment: Tried that, exactly the same issue :/

Comment: How did you install PHP?

Comment: It's an Amazon EC2 instance, so came preinstalled.

Comment: Might be an idea to remove PHP and add it the recommended microsoft way?